# Line 1, Character 1. Expected statement 800a0400

Tags: vbscript

This is my VB script:

```
<html> 
<body>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
   document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I saved this file as `new.vbs` and tried to run this script, but I got `"Line 1, Character 1. Expected statement 800a0400"` error on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: You had this tagged as VB.NET and VBA but you didn't even have it tagged as VBScript.  Bear in mind, while they share certain similarities, all three are significantly different technologies (especially VB.NET).  Please choose the tags more carefully.  If you get the tags wrong, anyone looking for questions in the right tags won't see your question.  Proper tagging is important in order for you to get the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

This script may be used into a browser. Save it as .html file, and try with Internet Explorer. Other browsers like Chrome, will not. Consider use Javascript, instead, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a plain/Windows Script Host VBScript program, put

```
WScript.Echo "Hello, world"
```

into New.vbs and run it from a console using

```
cscript New.vbs
```